# NoClassDefFoundError when starting OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I was running OrientDB community 2.1.11. I ran a series of complex queries in a Java client over a remote connection, and caused the server to run out of memory. (Server on a different machine from client. Both are Windows machines.)

When I tried to restart the Orient server I got a NoClassDefFoundError.

I created a clean install of OrientDB 2.1.14 (community) and restarted the server. I received the same error:

```
O:\OrientDb\orientdb-community-2.1.14\bin>server.bat

(ASCII image omitted)

2016-03-31 23:41:14:447 WARNI Cannot find default script language for javascript [OScriptManager]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:478 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=26,168MB (heap=455MB os=28,671MB disk=1,030,470MB) [orientechnologies]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:603 INFO  Loading configuration from: O:/OrientDb/orientdb-community-2.1.14/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:822 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.14 (build 2.1.x@r4d21d805fc9574c11b334a453161920cc1ed9cb7; 2016-03-30 15:26:04+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:837 INFO  Databases directory: O:\OrientDb\orientdb-community-2.1.14\databases [OServer]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:868 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:884 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-03-31 23:41:14:900 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.1.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.setup(ODocument.java:2428)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.<init>(ODocument.java:106)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.installDynamicPlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:333)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:203)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugins(OServerPluginManager.java:293)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startup(OServerPluginManager.java:94)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:953)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:336)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
```

Any idea what might be happening? What I can do to get my server to run again?

Comment: Hi Rob, when you created the build has everything gone right ? Have you already tried to recreate the clean install ? I'm trying your case with a clean install with maven but I can't get your exception.

Comment: Install process: download http://orientdb.com/download.php?email=x@x.com&file=orientdb-community-2.1.14.zip&os=win and unzip. Everything was normal up to the observed exception.

Comment: Hi Rob, your link worked for me. Did you change any settings before launching 2.1.14 version ?

Comment: Hi @Rob can you give us your information about java (e.g. JKD..)?

Comment: O:\OrientDb\orientdb-community-2.1.14\bin>java -version

java version "1.8.0_73"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: No changes during installation (with the sole exception of entering the password when prompted.)

Comment: might be related to this https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3501